# Better to split html into pieces and join with variables or use test.replace() instead 10 times?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Suppose my html template has 10 things that need to be replaced.

would it be better to split html into 10 variables and then add things together..

```
 a1 = '<html><title>'
 a2 = '</title><body>'

 var = 'title'

 output = a1 + var + a2
```

or is it better to simply use..

```
     a1 = '<html><title>000</title><body>'
     var = 'title'
     output = a1.replace('000',var)
```

if there are 10 things to be replaced for example. ?

Comment: Neither of those is a good way of doing things, since neither of them is actually HTML-syntax aware. Real template engines need to be able to deal with things like quoting and escaping -- particularly if you're substituting user-provided data, in which case a failure to do so properly would have serious security concerns.

Comment: Anyhow -- a good template engine (such as Jinja) will compile your templates down to Python bytecode, meaning you get all the flexibility of modern tooling, and don't give up performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use string format:

```
 a1 = '<html><title>{0}</title><body>{1}</body></html>'
 vars = ['title', 'body']
 output = a1.format(*vars)
```

or

```
 a1 = '<html><title>{0}</title><body>{1}</body></html>'
 var1 = 'title'
 var2 = 'body'
 output = a1.format(var1, var2)
```

Here {index} tells format which variable to substitute in for that position. You can also re-use the index - `'{0}{0}{1}{1}'.format('Test1', 'Test2')` will give you `'Test1Test1Test2Test2'` You can also use a lot of format specifiers. Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec